# Why am I getting Tensorflow Serving module import error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to use TensorFlow Serving. I installed TensorFlow serving with [these](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/setup) instructions.

When I attempted use this line in my python code

```
from tensorflow_serving.session_bundle import exporter
```

I got this problem

```
>>> from tensorflow_serving.session_bundle import exporter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow_serving.session_bundle
```

Why am I getting this problem? Am I missing something to build TensorFlow to include this module?

P.S.: Hello World TensorFlow application is working fine in my setup.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow (`tf.__version__`) are you using?

Comment: @musically_ut: 
>>> tf.__version__
'1.1.0-rc2'

Comment: And `tensorflow_serving.__version__`?

Comment: @musically_ut: >>> tensorflow_serving.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tensorflow_serving' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending countless hours, I managed to find the solution.

When I changed the line

```
from tensorflow_serving.session_bundle import exporter
```

to

```
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import exporter
```

It seems TF developers decided to change their session_bundle package location in the source tree.

Comment: It's great that you found a solution! Was there a tutorial or documentation you copied the import line from? If so, you might want to send a pull request to update the documentation to save time for the next person who hits this issue!

Comment: @PeterHawkins: I examined the mnist_export.py file to see actual usage of TF serving. Then I noticed this change.  Unfortunately I could not find a clear documentation to explain this issue.  I think explicit change logs helps users to see this type of radical changes in the code.